# Событие :hover для строки таблицы, ячейки в которой обьеденены через rowspan

Tags: html, css, hover, table

[image: Сам вопрос красноречиво отображается на картинке.]
Структура у строки следующая:

```css
tr:hover {
  background-color: var(--aluminium-60);
}

.dark-table__body {
  padding: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid var(--aluminium);
}

.dark-table__body--center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--row-title" rowspan="3">
        Enterprise Mobility n Security
      </td>
      <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--center">
          Microsoft Intune
       </td>
       <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--center" rowspan="3">
         EMSE3
       </td>
       <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--center" rowspan="3">
         EMSE5
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--center">
         Azure Information Protection Plan 1
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="dark-table__body dark-table__body--center">
          Limited AAD Features
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Вопрос в том, как при наведении выделять все три строки во второй колонке?

Comment: Но таких "тройных" блоков может быть много, ага?

Comment: да, неопределенное количество

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пришлось заключать необходимую строку в `<tbody>` и задавать :hover уже его классу.

Comment: Вариант... если не смущает наличие нескольких tbody) Думал про создание отдельных блоков-таблиц внутри каждого tr.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME хм, можно попробовать